# how do i connect xamarin with visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin-studio

I have knowledge in dotnet, would like to create app's using xamarin with visual studio but i dont know how to do this and what's the requirement nu. i have windows 7 OS installed with Visual Studio 2012. kindly give me a reply soon

Answer (score 0):

You can download Xamarin for visual studio here: http://xamarin.com/download.